Picking up container from Storage when bay is unreachable
I simulate container terminal and I want to use Material Handling Library -- Storage + transportFleet.
Containers are moved by transporters called "Reachstacker".
Key feature: they are capable to reach a second rack of storage
Use case scenario
without actually being closed to the target bay.
My question is: how to enforce transporter in Anylogic to put container in a rack's bay that is unreachable since there is no direct path?
I tried to work around Number of cells per slot but:

The logic of retrieving container back transformed to LIFO queue which is not right
In one bay could be a couple configurations of containers alignment (1 long container or 2 short ones). So I need this number of cells feature for configuring alignment

